# spring boot admin Cannot get information from client

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-boot-admin

Been Trying to setup Boot admin server. Connection to a client instance fails
on `IOException - An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine` even though all relevant endpoints are reachable (and spring security is not in the classpath)

On server start I'm getting:

```
Couldn't retrieve status for Instance(id=91e01a92b3bf, version=0, registration=Registration(name=test, managementUrl=https://client-url:8080/actuator, healthUrl=https://client-url:8080/actuator/health, serviceUrl=https://client-url:8080/, source=discovery), registered=true, statusInfo=StatusInfo(status=UNKNOWN, details={}), statusTimestamp=2018-10-24T13:57:58.816657Z, info=Info(values={}), endpoints=Endpoints(endpoints={health=Endpoint(id=health, url=https://client-url:8080/actuator/health)}), buildVersion=null, tags=Tags(values={}))
```

**Admin pom.xml**

```
 <dependency>
  <groupId>de.codecentric</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-admin-starter-server</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-cloud-commons</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

**Admin application.yml** per [admin docs](http://codecentric.github.io/spring-boot-admin/current/#spring-cloud-discovery-static-config)

```
spring:
  cloud:
    discovery:
      client:
        simple:
          instances:
            test:
            - uri: https://client-url:8080
              metadata:
                management.context-path: /actuator
```

**Client application.yml**

```
management:
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: "*"
  endpoint:
    health:
      show-details: always
    metrics:
      enabled: true
```

Admin server logs are full with `org.apache.coyote.CloseNowException: Connection [74], Stream [21], This stream is not writable` errors

Answer (score 0):

Running the admin/client in debug mode will give more detailed logs in terms what exact url server is trying to hit and does the client getting any request from server or not. I came across similar situation and it was because there was difference of version between Spring Boot Admin and Client application.

Confirm that healthUrl=https://client-url:8080/actuator/health giving 200 OK response.
if not then you may want to change the below client property :

```
spring.boot.admin.client.api-path=/actuator
```

then check again that its giving 200 OK response.